# Cost Effective Option for Windows authentication / Server in the Cloud

Tags: windows, azure, active-directory

Question : What best option ( both cost effect and performs well ) for running windows server in the cloud and connecting to it from windows desktops. I only really need authentication.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Azure has a couple of different active directory solutions for authentication / AD services & paying extra to get things like SSO.  Much more cost effective than a full virtual server.